# Weird answer when solving an exponential equation

Tags: equation-solving

When I try to solve this exponential equation:

```
Solve[5^x == 25, x]
```

I get a very strange result:

```
{{x -> ConditionalExpression[(2 I \[Pi] C[1])/Log[5] + Log[25]/Log[5],
     C[1] \[Element] Integers]}}
```

How can this result be explained?
What's the correct way to solve an exponential equation?

Comment: From the documentation for `Solve`: "Solve[expr, vars] assumes by default that quantities appearing algebraically in inequalities are real, while all other quantities are complex."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply adding the restriction that your solution should be `Real` yields the "expected" value.

```
Solve[5^x == 25, x, Reals]
```

> {{x -> 2}}

Comment: Also `Solve[5^x == 25, x, Integers]` or `Solve[5^x == 25, x, Rationals]` or `Solve[5^x == 25, x] /. C[1] -> 0 // FullSimplify`